# Acessing Microsoft CRM Online using Office 365 authentication

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

yesterday I created a new installation of Microsoft CRM Online.
Now I'm trying to access the webservice using the sdk provided from Microsoft.
When i try to connect to Microsoft CRM Online I get this error:

An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

I read in some posts that it can be the hours difference between my machine and the CRM Online Server, but I've tried running this code unsuccessfully using all the hours.

```cs
CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://desenvolvimento.crm2.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc; Username=jones.rives@desenvolvimento.onmicrosoft.com; Password=XXX;");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);

Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "Test Account";
account.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid accountId = service.Create(account);
```

Is it different to connect to CRM Online using 365 credentials? I really can't find the problem, and I've tried many solutions, but none worked.
Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the endpoint inside the connection string when you use the simplified connection, just the organization url.

Assuming your url is correct (meaning you can login using a browser), try with:

```cs
CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://desenvolvimento.crm2.dynamics.com; Username=jones.rives@desenvolvimento.onmicrosoft.com; Password=XXX;");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);

Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "Test Account";
Guid accountId = service.Create(account);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tested without the endpoint, exactly the way you showed in the code above, and yet it didn't work. I caught the same exception.

Comment: just to be sure, you are able to login right? if yes maybe is because your server is in the new Brazilian data center and the dll maybe is not able to handle the new host(crm2). I need to run some tests to verify this

Comment: thank you very much! You are completely right! I created another trial installation from CRM Online using United States as country, and I got this https://testedev.crm.dynamics.com
Using this server my code works like a charm!

Comment: @FelipeMaurício I confirm this issue, I tried with a new South America organization and it's not possible to authenticate. I will update you if I find a solution.

Comment: @FelipeMaurício I tested now and the connection works also with the south america data center